# Modified maximum cost after replacement

Tags: algorithm, math, maximize

Initial cost of items is provided by an array denoting cost of each items.

These costs can be altered as if we are allowed to change the cost according to the offer applicable on the given day.(More clarification through example)

For e.g., Cost of items are **1, 3, 5**

And **D, A, B** represents that on **Dth** day item having cost of **A** can be changed to **B** or **vice-versa**.

Now, following lines represents **D, A, B**:

1 4 3

1 1 3

2 6 22

3 5 8

On a given day, any offer can be applied any number of times to any number of items.

All details of offers are provided earlier so that you can accept/decline it depending whether it provides you maximum cost or not.

We have to obtain the maximum cost of items that can be achieved so Item having cost of **1** is changed to **3** and then **3** is changed to **4** and then **5** is changed to **8**, **2nd** day offer can't be applied as no items are having cost of 6 or 22 and also these costs can't be achieved anyhow.

Hence, the final costs of items are **4**, **4**, **8**, so maximum cost is **16**.

How to approach the solution when the data are large enough ?

Comment: Ok, do you have a question?

Comment: For large data, I don't know how to approach the solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain your question explicitly, as in as a last sentence ending in a question mark, and check the title: Does a casual reader recognise your specific problem? When deciding on offers `applicable on the given day`, do you know later ones?

Comment: @greybeard Yes, all later offers are known.

Comment: Do not comment comments regarding your own posts if an explication or other change seems in order: edit the question instead. Make it look as hard as it is by including an example where 1) a lower intermediate value has to be taken 2) the order of offers matters.

Answer (score 0):

How to find maximum value in the first place?
Observations:

- items are independent
  One might just operate on any items possible sequences of values, possibly ignoring lots of offers
- offers are partially ordered by day, and depend on (current) item value, not type
  One might put together possible sequences for all "end-of-day" values resulting from `replacement`s, each possibly to be used by many items

(Anyone is welcome to improve this post. Each OP (MetaD, for one) is welcome to answer her/his own question.)